# Empty Message Is not showing in empty table in ng-repeat angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, html-table

Empty Text is not showing In table 
I am using table 
which is empty Now

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Privilege Name</th>
            <th>PageUrl</th>
            <th>Can Add</th>
            <th>Can Edit</th>
            <th>Can Delete</th>
            <th>Can View</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="obj in getAssignedPrivilegeslist" ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length !=0 && getAssignedPrivilegeslist !='null'">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{obj.PageName}}</td>
            <td><a ng-href="{{'//'+obj.PageUrl }}">{{obj.PageUrl}}</a></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Add" value="Add" ng-model="obj.CanCreate" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="Edit" ng-model="obj.CanEdit" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Delete" value="Delete" ng-model="obj.CanDelete" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="View" value="View" ng-model="obj.CanView" />
            </td>
            <td ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length==0" id="nofoundop">Please Select Operator</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then I set a `<td>` if data length is 0 then show the given message but it is not showing.
Please help I will be very thankful to you all.

Comment: FYI, `ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length !=0 && getAssignedPrivilegeslist !='null'"` would be better written as `ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length"`. If the list's length is any number besides 0, it'll evaluate as true, and if it's 0 or can't be accessed (because it's undefined), it'll evaluate as false. However, you'll run into problems if you're actually storing the string literal `'null'` as its value, so change that to `null` instead if you were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**These three changes you have to made in your code :**

- Instead of `ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length !=0"` you can use `ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length"`. As suggested by [Harris Weinstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1856885/harris-weinstein) in his comment that if the list's length is any number besides 0, it'll evaluate as true, and if it's 0 or can't be accessed (because it's undefined), it'll evaluate as false.
- Instead of using string literal `getAssignedPrivilegeslist !='null'` use `getAssignedPrivilegeslist !=null`.
- Put your element having error message outside the `<tr>` as you already put the `ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length !=0"` in the `<tr>` tag.

You can use like this outside your `<tr>` tag as suggested by [sexta13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709664/sexta13):

```
<tr ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length==0" >
   <td id="nofoundop">
      please select operator
   </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your logic not very well structured.

You have your

```
<td ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length==0" id="nofoundop">
    Please Select Operator
</td>
```

inside a ng-repeat that will only happen if getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length !=0 && getAssignedPrivilegeslist !='null'

You should have another tr outside the ng-repeat with something like this:

```
<tr ng-show="getAssignedPrivilegeslist.length==0" >
   <td id="nofoundop">
      please select operator
   </td>
</tr>
```